# Curl init() Disabled for Security Reasons, while trying to activate chikita plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

So I am trying to activate the chikita plugin for my website. I keep getting this:

```
Warning: curl_init() has been disabled for security reasons in
/www/mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/chitika-premium/premium.php
on line 518
```

Any thoughts on how to bypass this? I am insanely new to php and wordpress. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Free webhosting is garbage. Get a real host and things like curl and other php functions won't be disabled and WordPress and everything else will function correctly.

Comment: ahh, makes sense, not being able to change php ini memory and such. That's dumb, I'll be looking for other hosting options...

Comment: Try Bluehost; not GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

I am amazed you are using premium plugins on free web hosting? You will be banging your head against wall quite often in this case. Premium hosting is not expensive these days. You can get that for few buks a month / year.. Google is your best friend :)